# Button click not working for custom UIView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Code for the Custom UIView:

Please check the video too here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kbrOxXWcJIi4vkiqMNer3exBr5cOWgDz

```
 import UIKit
    protocol PostAttachmentFullScreenViewDelegate: class {
        func closeAttachmentFullView()
    }

    class PostAttachmentFullScreenView: UIView {

        weak var delegate: PostAttachmentFullScreenViewDelegate?

        @IBOutlet var backgroundView: UIImageView!

        @IBOutlet var closeButton: UIButton!
        @IBAction func closeViewAction(_ sender: Any) {
            print("will call delegate to put it off")
            self.delegate?.closeAttachmentFullView()
        }


        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)

            let _ = commonInitialization()
            backgroundView.image = UIImage(named: "ScrollImageTop1")
           closeButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
             let _ = commonInitialization()

            backgroundView.image = UIImage(named: "ScrollImageTop1")
            closeButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        }

        func commonInitialization() -> UIView
        {
            let bundle = Bundle.init(for: type(of: self))
            let nib = UINib(nibName: "PostAttachmentFullScreenView", bundle: bundle)
            let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
            view.frame = bounds
            view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
            addSubview(view)
            return view

        }


    }
```

usage in ViewController (I am defining an instance of the custom view and putting it inside the Scroll View):

```
        var frame  = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:0, height:0)
        let blue = PostAttachmentFullScreenView()
        blue.delegate = self
        blue.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        blue.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        blue.backgroundView.image = fileAttachments[1]

        frame.origin.x = attachmentsScrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat (0)
        frame.size = attachmentsScrollView.frame.size
        blue.frame = frame
        attachmentsScrollView.addSubview(blue)


extension NewPostViewController : PostAttachmentFullScreenViewDelegate
{
    func closeAttachmentFullView() {
        print("hiding attachments view")
        attachmentSuperView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

To my surprise it doesn't even print - "will call delegate to put it off".
I am not able to understand what's wrong here. Please help me understand the issue and correct it. Thank you.

Comment: Enable `isUserInteractionEnabled` of your `PostAttachmentFullScreenView`.

Comment: @Kuldeep, doesn't work. Is there something wrong with init functions?

Comment: You can try checking all of the superviews of your button for `isUserInteractionEnabled` or try to add your `UIViewController` with `addChildViewController`, maybe the reference to it gets lost when you only add it as view.

Comment: @EnrikQaz can you please check hierarchy of Views or upload document Outline of that ViewController to see hierarchy

Comment: Use constraints, not frames...

Comment: can you share. DEMO

Comment: @Sh_Khan, please check the video.

Comment: please try with `yourView.bringSubview(toFront: yourButton)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing programmatic approach and xib approach.

As you have added `IBOultet` and `IBAction` that means you are using `xib` for the `UIView`.

In that scenario you have to load the `UIView` `xib` when initialising the view.

Add an `extension` for `UIView` in your project:

```
extension UIView {
    class func fromNib<T: UIView>() -> T {
        return Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(String(describing: T.self), owner: nil, options: nil)![0] as! T
    }
}
```

when you are initialising your view add it like this :

```
let blue : PostAttachmentFullScreenView = UIView.fromNib()
blue.delegate = self
blue.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
blue.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
blue.backgroundView.image = fileAttachments[1]

frame.origin.x = attachmentsScrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat (0)
frame.size = attachmentsScrollView.frame.size
blue.frame = frame
attachmentsScrollView.addSubview(blue)
```

and the delegate and button action methods will work.

you missed this :

[image]

Comment: Throws unexpected errors:  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x604000008f40> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key backgroundView.'

Comment: That is because you haven't connected the referencing outlet of `UIImageView` in your xib with `backgroundView` in your `UIView - PostAttachmentFullScreenView `.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Getting an error "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key..." means you have a broken outlet, not that the approach of loading the XIB is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You never set the target/action on your button. Somewhere you need to call `addTarget(_:action:for:)` to set the target/action on the button. Also, what connects the button to your `PostAttachmentFullScreenView` as an outlet?

Comment: Please check the video in the detail.

Comment: Ok, you do have the IBAction connected in your XIB, but as Amit points out in his answer, you're not loading your view from a XIB file, so the target/action still isn't getting connected. You need to do that, and fix the broken outlet that's causing your crash.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an obvious one but for me (Xcode 10.1) adding all missing UI constraints to the UIButton in question (at least 4 constraints) fixed the error for me in my custom view:

[image: Add New Constrain button at the bottom]

[image: Add New Constraint options]

Make sure you add enough constraints (typically 4 constraints) or enough to have all warnings regarding **missing constraints** removed. After doing this and attaching the button with Ctrl + drag from View to corresponding swift code, the click was being detected and working properly.

Hope this helps.